# Why doesn't HTML allow me to add event handlers in the same way as JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Why this code works in **React JSX** but doesn't work in **HTML**:

The code below is just an attribute of tag .
A function **handleClick** just show *console.log*

This code works in **React JSX** code:

```js
onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(1)}
```

This doesnt' work in **HTML**:

```js
onclick={() => handleClick(1)}
```

1. Why I should put **handleClick** function in another function in React JSX?
2. Why it doesn't work in **HTML**?

Comment: Because HTML is not JSX. JSX is syntactic sugar that's transpiled into JS. HTML is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ReactJS has its own JSX interpreter/compiler, which is how it is able to work.
- In "VanillaJS" (really, just *JavaScript*), you don't get that benefit.

  - Unless you want to import the JSX engine into your JS project and deal with those dependencies.

> Why I should put `handleClick` function in another function in React JSX?

I need more context to answer this question.

> Why it doesn't work in HTML?

```
onclick={() => handleClick(1)}
```

This doesn't work in VanillaJS because `onclick` is a function-property, but you *can* simply overwrite the `onclick` function-property with a new function:

```
someButton.onclick = () => handleClick(1); // Warning: this will replace any existing `onclick` function property.
```

In fact, this is how JavaScript programmers used to add multiple event-handlers to the same event before `addEventListener` was added to the DOM and support became widespread (around the late-2000s):

```
var currentOnClick = someButton.onclick;
someButton.onclick = function( e ) {
    if( currentOnClick ) currentOnClick( e );
    // do stuff 
};
```

Of course the official way is to use the DOM's `addEventListener` function:

```
someButton.addEventListener( 'click', handleClick.bind(this) );
// or:
someButton.addEventListener( 'click', () => handleClick(1) );
// or:
someButton.addEventListener( 'click', e => handleClick(1) );
```

If you want to make JavaScript's event-handling code more succinct then patch `EventTarget` (the parent type of `addEventListener`):

```
Object.defineProperty( EventTarget.prototype, 'onclick2', {

    get() {
        if( typeof this.onclickHandlers == 'undefined' ) {
           this.onclickHandlers = [];
        }
        return this.onclickHandlers;
    }

    set( handlerFunc ) {

        if( typeof this.onclickHandlers == 'undefined' ) {
           this.onclickHandlers = [];
        }

        this.onclickHandlers.push( handlerFunc );

        this.addEventListener( 'click', handlerFunc );
    }

} );
```

Usage:

```
someButton.onclick2 = () => doSomething();
```

Comment: I finding that something like this: <button onclick="() => handleClick();">Click Me</button> Does not work...

Comment: @BrianOgden I didn't know you were talking about inline attribute assignment in HTML.

Comment: That's because in an `onclick` HTML attribute you need to provide code that executes the action, not just provides a function. So it needs to *call* it. It you want you can do `onclick="(() => handleClick())();"`, but then you might as well do `onclick="handleClick()"`

Comment: @Dai I thought the OP was talking about inline attribute assignment in HTML but the OP is not so don't listen to my comment, I thought I was being helpful that you could add to your answer regarding inline attribute assignment but it is not necessary because the OP is not asking about it